# Saving Android tests

Tags: android, terminal, android-testing, spoon

I am building my tests with Espresso, and running with Spoon. I run tests with this line via terminal:

> gradle spoon

I am looking for a way to save my results.I need to run multiple times, and view the results after a few hours. As of now, when I run a test it overwrites the previous test result.

---

> gradle spoon >> ~/documents/dev/wolf/test_results/test.txt

I know this command wouldn't save multiple files, but if I could at least control the name of the test in question, I could go from there.

This only saves what is printed in the terminal. Spoon saves test results as an HTML in the `build` folder of my app. Is there anyway I can save the test results without overwriting them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I ended up creating an executable jar that would copy the results folder and append the date of creation to the folder name. This allowed the results to be stored, and kept the new results in the same location.

Comment: I just built a script that would go and mv the results to another folder. So this was a close answer.

Comment: Are you able to share the code to be able to create this jar file?